# Having 2 Lists, how do you find overlap between them in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express.  I have 2 Lists of zip codes each of which do NOT contain duplicates in and of themselves (the list items are all distinct).  However,  when comparing the 2 Lists there is some overlap, and I want to make a third list that contains only the overlap.  Is there a method I can use to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the Intersect method. http://www.dotnetperls.com/intersect

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx):

```
var duplicates = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

Answer (score 6):

If they are distinct anyway, you could also use a `HashSet<T>`.

It has a method [`IntersectWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx),for example:

```
HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(list1);
HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(list2);
set1.IntersectWith(set2);
```

MSDN:

> Modifies the current HashSet object to contain only elements that
>   are present in that object and in the specified collection.

Here's a simple measurement (`HashSet.IntersectWith` vs. `IEnumerable.Intersect)`. As you can see,in this sample HashSet is a lot faster than the list approach.

```
var list1 = new List<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    list1.Add("Item" + i);
var list2 = new List<String>();
for (int i = 500000; i < 5000000; i++)
    list2.Add("Item" + i);

var watch1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(list1);
HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(list2);
watch1.Start();
set1.IntersectWith(set2);
watch1.Stop();

var watch2 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
watch2.Start();
List<String> intersectingList = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
watch2.Stop();

var hashSetTime = watch1.Elapsed.ToString();  // 0.27 seconds
var listTime = watch2.Elapsed.ToString();  // 1.46 seconds
```

So `Enumerable.Intersect` is nearly 6 times slower than `HashSet.IntersectWith`. `ToList` is required since you want to *"make a third list that contains only the overlap"*.

Comment: +1 Interesting comparison. I would have never thought about using a HashSet.

Comment: Hashset intersects are certainly faster but if you're starting with Lists then shouldn't your timings include the time to convert the lists to hashsets?

Comment: @ebpower: Creating the two HashSets + `set1.IntersectWith(set2);` takes 0.82 seconds, so its still faster. But my point was that he should consider to replace his lists with sets from the beginning, since he mentioned that they always contain distinct values.

Comment: If you count the time to convert to a HashSet, then you will find this to even faster: 

var set3 = new HashSet<String>(list1);
var anotherList = list2.Where(n => set3.Contains(n)).ToList();

Comment: @ebpower: 0.72 seconds, so another interesting variant. If both are `HashSets`, the `IntersectsWith` needs only `O(n)` as opposed to one HashSet and the other List `O(n + m)`. That's why i've created two sets. But the best option is to use them right from the start.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - You're key point is about starting with HashSets from the outset, which would leave it as O(n). But if the problem requires converting from Lists, then the variant is faster because it saves the pass into the second HashSet. And if the lambda includes AsParallel() then it's nearly as fast as InsertsectsWith on a multi-core system.

Comment: @Tim The statement: If they are distinct anyway, you could also use a HashSet<T> is irrelevant in this case, as the IEnumerable resulting from:

Comment: @Tim The statement: If they are distinct anyway, you could also use a HashSet<T> is irrelevant in this case, as the IEnumerable resulting from:set1.IntersectWith(set2); will contain only distinct items regardless of the 2 lists containing duplicate items (only one instance of each common item will be selected for the intersection). What I mean, it is always worth to cast the lists into HashSets and perform the intersection operation on the HashSets, despite of the penalty of casting.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the zip codes are just `string`s (or `int`s) you can get the overlap using Linq's `Intersect` method:

```
 List<string> overlap = zips1.Intersect(zips2).ToList();
```

Comment: @Tim The statement: If they are distinct anyway, you could also use a HashSet<T> is irrelevant in this case, as the IEnumerable resulting from:set1.IntersectWith(set2); will contain only distinct items regardless of the 2 lists containing duplicate items (only one instance of each common item will be selected for the intersection). What I mean, it is always worth to cast the lists into HashSets and perform the intersection operation on the HashSets, even if the penalty of casting must be paid.